Python/PySpark - Programmatically send json_string column to REST API
I have a dataframe which I stream in using Spark Structured Streaming .readStream():



Id
json_data




123
{color: "red", value: "#f00"}


125
{color: "blue", value: "#f45"}



I want to send each json_data from each row to a rest API, as a json payload. What is the best way of doing this?
I'm aware of a dataframe writer (https://docs.databricks.com/en/structured-streaming/foreach.html) for Databricks however unclear how I'd do this.
Do I need to write the column into a python dictionary?
Bit confused how this script would work, the streaming data comes in and appends onto the dataframe, but I need the json_data column (which is stored as a string) to be used as a payload.

You can apply UDF on the stream. here's an example. https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/apache-spark-structured-streaming-operations-5-of-6-40d907866fa7

Try this:
def export_to_api(microBatchOutputDF, batchId):
  microBatchOutputDF_array = microBatchOutputDF.collect()
  for row in microBatchOutputDF_array:
    json_content = row.json_data
    # Enter solution for exporting to api
    <>

# Write the output of a streaming aggregation query into Delta table
(streaming_data.writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .foreachBatch(export_to_api)
)

